# Grep perl syntax and copyright character

Tags: grep, cygwin

I am trying to pull some links out of text that I downloaded of off the internet using grep, but keep getting "Aborted (core dumped)". When using grep I tend to use `-P` as I prefer to use perl syntax (and I like to prevent greediness using `?`). Grep itself has no troubles applying a pattern to the file without `-P`.

Now, I am fairly new to the command line (and loving it!), so I can't work out how to sort this.

Note that this issue occurs with almost any pattern. Example : `grep '\.jpg' file.txt -oP`

I would like to run: `grep '.+?\.jpg' file.txt -oP`

Update: It seems that the root of the problem is infact this piece of "code":

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Bookmark site script- © Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/

/* Modified to support Opera */
function bookmarksite(title,url){
if (window.sidebar) // firefox
    window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url, "");
else if(window.opera && window.print){ // opera
    var elem = document.createElement('a');
    elem.setAttribute('href',url);
    elem.setAttribute('title',title);
    elem.setAttribute('rel','sidebar');
    elem.click();
} 
else if(document.all)// ie
    window.external.AddFavorite(url, title);
}
</script>
```

source: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/addbook.htm
I first assumed that the "*" was causing problems. Testing indicates that the copyright symbol was infact the problem. Is it possible that this is an issue with different encodings? Even copying and pasting into a new document causes the same issues though.

My environment is: "Cygwin, Windows 8.1 64bit"
Locale output:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Grep version:

```
  $ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.14.56-1e3d
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
```

Comment: Could we see a minimal example of the file that reproduces the error? I tried with a file with 100 lines of 224000 characters and it worked fine.

Comment: I too tried with about 50 lines with each line 227500 char long and grep worked fine.

Comment: May be you are hitting this bug: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?36842

Comment: @Ketan I doubt it, that's a 10 year old version of `grep`.

Comment: Okay, so after further investigation I have found that it is infact *not* the long line lengths causing the problem. However, what I have found is an issue with the header of the file. I have updated the post to reflect my findings

Comment: Still works fine here. Please show us the output of `locale`, also tell us something about your system. Is this Linux? What version of `grep`?

Comment: I am running this inside of Cygwin. First post has been updated with locale information

Comment: Ah, that's the kind of thing that you should mention in your question. Please [edit] it to explain what your setup is. Also show us the output of `grep --version`. The actual regex you are trying to match would be useful as well. That way we can give you specific workarounds.

Comment: Post updated with required information (sorry, did think of that to start with). The regex has also been updated

Comment: Is `LC_ALL=C` give the same error?

Comment: OT: I find it a bit funny that someone thinks that they can get away with "copyrighting" such common/simple code :-)

Comment: @Gnouc `LC_ALL=C` worked wonderfully for what I am doing. I see that there can be a lot of side effects depending on the encoding of the input values, but my data is pretty straightforward ASCII (except for that one character). This is a good temporary solution, but for times when accuracy is required I will use terdon's solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have access to a cygwin system so I can't test this, but since you want to use Perl regexes, why not use Perl?

```
perl -ne 'print "$_\n" for /.+?\.jpg/g;' file.txt
```

or

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($(i)~/.+?\.jpg/){print $(i)}}}' file.txt
```

However, I suspect that you want to match the shortest string of non-whitespace characters that end in `.jpg` which is not what that regex matches (though the `awk` solution will work anyway since the fields are split on whitespace). You might want to run this instead:

```
perl -ne '@a=/[^\s]+\.jpg/g; print "$_\n" for @a' file.txt
```

or

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($(i)~/.+?\.jpg/){print $(i)}}}' file.txt
```

or, simple `grep`:

```
grep -o '[^[:space:]]*.jpg' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution and thanks to @Gnouc. Gnouc's is a good quick fix, but these  ones are very impressive. Thanks!